# Java HashMap null values or keys

Tags: java, hashmap

Is it possible that I can put values directly to the key has null values of `HashMap`?

What I want is to check if the value of one key in `HashMap` is `null` then i'm going to fill it.

Comment: Yes,  that is possible.

Comment: Map Keys are not map Values. While permissible, one generally wouldn't "put a null value" (as it would generally just not be in the map to begin with!) and there is at most one "null key" (which is the same) per map.

Comment: @tuturyokgaming are you simply looking to see how to find the key which has null value and then put a value there? yes it would be fairly easy to do that. please let me know and I'll post the code for that.

Comment: @tuturyokgaming I have added the answer. It is a simple program, find and replaces null with any value you want.

Answer (score 0):

If `map.get(key)` returns null, you know that either the key is not present in the Map or that it's present and has a null value.

To distinguish between the two :

```
if (map.containsKey(key)) {
    if (map.get(key) == null) {
        // key is present and has null value
    }
} else {
    // key is not present in the Map
}
```

Comment: Then how can I fill the null value or key?

Comment: @tuturyokgaming `map.put(key,value)`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Eran answer I should note that having `null` values in `Map` is discouraged. First, it's not supported by every Map implementation. For example, `ConcurrentHashMap` does not support `null` values, so if later this `Map` will be shared across several threads and you decide to move to `ConcurrentHashMap` you will discover that you cannot do this without getting rid of nulls. Second, most of the new Java-8 API methods `getOrDefault`, `merge`, `computeIfAbsent` do not behave friendly with `null` values: usually they assume that `null` value is the same as the absence of the value. Finally handling `null` values is somewhat slower as you need to check against the same key twice (first via `containsKey`, second via `get`).

Thus in general if it's possible you should avoid null values in maps. Sometimes it's possible to introduce a special constant which designates an absence of the value. That depends on particular task.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently need to add null values to the key now. Because I'm reading a text file and adding some of the lines to arraylist and arraylist will be putted to the value, but what's happening is I'm reading the line and splitting it up to CSV. So What am I doing is, I'm reading all the lines first with comma on it then stored it to key of HashMap. Second I'm storing it to arraylist and need to put it to the keys that has null value. I'm using JDK-6

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest (can be improved/code reviewed further) complete program. It  will find the `key` and if the corresponding value is `null` it will replace that null with yourNewValue.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class SimpleMapKeyValue {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("A", 5);
        map.put("B", 10);
        map.put("D", null);
        map.put("E", 23);

        int yourNewValue = 100;

        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
            if (entry.getValue() == null) {
                map.put(entry.getKey(),yourNewValue);
            }
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```